# Anonymous class member cannot be reinitialized

Tags: java, anonymous-class

I am reinitializing the member variable of a local class and am getting a compilation error. What is wrong here? Why will this not compile? Thanks!

This will not compile

```
public class TestSomething {

public void someMethod(){
    class LocalClassInner{
        int i=100; // Error on this line.Syntax error on token ";", , expected

        i=200;
    }       
}

}
```

This compiles just fine

```
public class TestSomething {

public void someMethod(){
    class LocalClassInner{
        int i=100;
        //i=200;
    }       
}}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't really an local class problem.  You can't put assignment statements at the "top-level" of any class.

Assignment statements need to go in a method, constructor, static initializer, or instance initializer.

WHen you wrote

```
int i = 100;
```

you were actually declaring a *field* of the inner class (as you know).  You can reassign this field, provided you did so in a constructor, method, etc.

**ADDENDUM**

The following uses an instance initializer, just for fun:

```
public void someMethod() {
    class LocalClassInner {
        int i = 100;
        {i=200;}
    }           
}
```

It compiles fine, see http://ideone.com/qjnv3

Comment: Thanks Ray. Makes perfect sense. Just wish that the compiler error was a bit more meaningful.

Answer (score 0):

The second assignment is misplaced. You cannot put regular code outside of a method, constructor or initializer. This has nothing to do with the anonymous class.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change the assignment of i it needs to go in a method.

Like this:

```
public class TestSomething {

public void someMethod(){
    class LocalClassInner{
        int i=100;
        private void setI()
        {
            i=200;
        }
    }       
}}
```